# What's the difference between "feat", "artist1 X artist 2", "artist1 Vs. artist2" and "artist1 & artist 2"?

Tags: terminology

In songs with multiple artists, I've seen 4 different ways to credit the other artists. 'Feat.', '&', 'X' and 'Vs'. How are they used?

(I have no example of 'V', but I've seen it used.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if there's really a convention. I feel most of these are used interchangeably. For what it's worth, though: 'Feat' implies a short cameo, like a guest solo or a rapped bridge. '&' implies more of a 50/50 collaboration, or at least a joint effort. I've never seen 'X', but 'Vs.' is (to my knowledge) used to imply a contest. Examples are rap-battles, DJ-faceoffs and the like. All in my opinion, of course.

Comment: This discussion from Sound Design.SE also answers your question: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/27409/meaning-of-feat-pres-vs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feat: means 'featuring', its when some artist appear on another's song providing some of the music or vocals.(one has the song, the other is a guest)

&: means a collaboration between the two artists to produce a song by both(like equals and not a guest)

Vs: means 'versus', is mostly used when mashing up or mixing two songs together, or when a studio has two artists work on heir own parts but into a single song(this is in a competitive manner)

x: could have the same meaning as 'vs' but maybe as '&', it is not widely used so am not sure how they define it.

Comment: I've also seen "vs." indicating that two artists are just collaborating.